# How do I get a Netopia 3000 DSL modem to work in bridge mode?

Tags: networking, dsl

I'm going absolutely crazy here! I previously had a 2Wire DSL modem set to bridge mode with the Linksys router handling PPPoE auth. The router is a WRT54GL running Tomato. I recently moved and I'm trying to do the same thing with a new Motorola 3347 (Netopia 3000) and I can't get it to work to save my life.

On the modem I set the following:

DHCP Server: Off

Enable System Bridge: On

I then connected the router's WAN port to one of the modem's ethernet ports. The WAN status on the router shows a WAN IP of 0.0.0.0 and a status of "Connecting..." indefinitely.

I also tried unselecting Enable Gateway Option on the modem, which didn't do anything.

I've been at it for hours and I cannot get this to work. I just want the modem to act as a simple modem, passing the public IP to the router and not doing any routing or anything else. Please -PLEASE- help me get this working...

Comment: Did you setup PPPoE on the router? (Or confirm that you don't need it with this DSL connection?)

Comment: Yep, the router is configured exactly as it was at the prior location where it was working fine.